# Existe algum interpretador que retorna uma AST ampliada?

Tags: javascript

Estou usando um interpretador que retorna uma [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) que não sei como vou ler.

```
{
    clauses: [
        {
            body: [/* ...*/],
            condition: {/* ...*/},
            type: "IfClause"
        }
    ],
    type: "IfStatement"
}
```

Eu tenho que fazer um loop único para me lidar com essa árvore e um monte de condições para memorizar a propriedade que eu passei por dentro, etc. Tenho certeza que estou fazendo da forma errada, por isso gostaria de outro tipo de árvore.

```
{
    type: "IfClause"
},
{
    type: "Literal",
    value: false
},
{
    type: "BlockStatement"
},
{
    type: "Endif"
}
```

Ou tem outra solução?

Comment: A tua pergunta parece bem interessante mas está pouco clara, não percebo bem o que queres... dá uma olhada aqui: https://astexplorer.net/ é algo parecido que procuras?

Comment: @Sergio Ela é diferente ainda... retorna bloco de comandos dentro de um objeto de um bloco de comandos. Eu queria uma que não tivesse essa propriedade `body` nos objetos, uma bem ampla mesmo.

Comment: Ok, podes dar um exemplo de JS e como queres que ele apareça analizado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente o que você está querendo dificilmente vai ser suportado nativamente já que o próprio conceito de árvore é hierárquico por natureza.

Qual seu objetivo? Seria apenas "olhar" e conseguir ver o que quer mais facilmente? Ou seria processar via código a árvore gerada?

Uma lista é mais simples para você ver, mas é muito mais complicado para processar, já que você terá que recriar todos os contextos de cada bloco.

Se você tem dificuldades com esses blocos, pode ser que apenas precise se acostumar um pouco mais com algoritmos recursivos, por exemplo.

## Transformando a lista

Se você realmente precisar, uma lista *flat* pode ser gerada processando a AST.

Suponha que você tem a seguinte árvore fictícia:

```
var astTree = {
    type: "IfClause",
    base:
    {
        type: "Boolean",
        value: false
    },
    body: [
        { type: "Var" },
        { 
            type: "ForClause",
            body: [
                { type: "VarIncrement" }
            ]
        },
        { type: "Return" },
    ]
};
```

Então você pode se basear numa função recursiva que percorre todos os subelementos que possuem um `body` e adicionar num array. Exemplo:

```
var flatten = function(node) {
    var list = [];
    function consume(node) {
        list.push(node);
        if ('body' in node) {
            var endNode = { type: node.type + 'End' }
            node.type += "Start";
            node.body.forEach(consume);
            list.push(endNode);
            delete node.body;
        }
    }
    consume(node);
    return list;
}
```

E o resultado é:

```
[
  {
    "type": "IfClauseStart",
    "base": {
      "type": "Boolean",
      "value": false
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Var"
  },
  {
    "type": "ForClauseStart"
  },
  {
    "type": "VarIncrement"
  },
  {
    "type": "ForClauseEnd"
  },
  {
    "type": "Return"
  },
  {
    "type": "IfClauseEnd"
  }
]
```

#### [Veja o exemplo funcional](https://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/jw9tLkLe/)

Comment: Essa conversão parece solução à meu problema, embora falta chamar a função `consume` nas propriedades `base` em seu exemplo, pois uma função pode ser retornada lá e então o `body` da função teria que ser consumido.

Comment: @DavisLF Tem razão, não me atentei para esse detalhe, embora eu meu objetivo fosse dar apenas um exemplo é já imaginasse que existiriam mais casos que necessitariam de um tratamento específico. Com sorte não vai ter muitas situações diferentes e com poucos ajustes você consegue converter scripts mais complexos.